# Weird behavior of Dart Map's

Tags: dart

I was expecting the final c as

```
{a: {a: aA, b: aB}, b: {a: bA, b: bB}}
```

but it actually became

```
{a: {a: bA, b: bB}, b: {a: bA, b: bB}}
```

Dart code:

```
Map<String, String> a = {
  'a' : 'A',
  'b' : 'B',
};
Map<String, String> b = {};
Map<String, Map<String, String>> c = {};
void main() {
  for (var i in a.keys){
    for (var j in a.keys){
      b[j] = i+a[j];
      print('i: $i, j: $j, b[j]:${b[j]}');
    }
    print(b);
    c[i] = b;
    print(c);
  }
  print('final c is $c');
}
```

Its output:

```
i: a, j: a, b[j]:aA
i: a, j: b, b[j]:aB
{a: aA, b: aB}
{a: {a: aA, b: aB}}
i: b, j: a, b[j]:bA
i: b, j: b, b[j]:bB
{a: bA, b: bB}
{a: {a: bA, b: bB}, b: {a: bA, b: bB}}
final c is {a: {a: bA, b: bB}, b: {a: bA, b: bB}}
```

Why that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the `b` map after you have inserted it into the `c` map. I think the misunderstanding comes from you thinking that it is a copy of the object you are putting inside `c` but in fact it is a reference. If you prints the `hashCode` of `a` and `b` you can see they are in fact same object:

```
print(c['a'].hashCode == c['b'].hashCode); // true
```

What you properly want instead is to use a copy of `b` for each iteration of you first loop so the code looks like:

```
Map<String, String> a = {
  'a': 'A',
  'b': 'B',
};

Map<String, Map<String, String>> c = {};

void main() {
  for (var i in a.keys) {
    Map<String, String> b = {}; // <-- this is the fix

    for (var j in a.keys) {
      b[j] = i + a[j];
      print('i: $i, j: $j, b[j]:${b[j]}');
    }
    print(b);
    c[i] = b;
    print(c);
  }
  print('final c is $c'); // {a: {a: aA, b: aB}, b: {a: bA, b: bB}}
  print(c['a'].hashCode == c['b'].hashCode); // false
}
```